# SQL Server LocalDb And Compatibility Issues Between Workstations

Tags: sql-server, compatibility, localdb

I have both a laptop and desktop computer for development on both of which I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Express for Web. I'm developing an ASP.Net MVC application with Entity Framework code-first.

On the laptop, I was able to add a SQL Server LocalDb database file to the `App_Data` folder, however when trying to open the database on the desktop machine (with the same version of Express 2015 for Web installed - from the same installer), I get error messages saying something along the lines of:

> The database file you are attempting to connect to is not compatible with the current instance of SQL Server. To continue, you must upgrade this database file...

Having been through this loop several times with endless issues relating to compatibility of LocalDb databases between workstations, I'm getting a bit fed up. Every time I've had compatibility issues between machines whereby I've upgraded the database only for the other workstation not to be compatible with that version.

My question is: is it worth persisting with LocalDb or should I just move the database across to SQL Server Express and be done with it? I like the idea of LocalDb as I can keep the database in the solution.

Comment: SQL Server **LocalDB** ***IS*** SQL Server Express - just a programmer-targeted version that doesn't get installed as a Windows service, but as a version that launches when your application that needs it starts up. It's the same software in the end. Most likely, you have an issue with two different **versions** of SQL Server - you can **never** "go back", e.g. restore a newer database (e.g. 2014) onto an older SQL Server version (e.g. 2012).

Comment: @marc_s I'm not 100% convinced as I've just attached the database file to my local SQL Server Express server and its worked first time without any compatibility issue messages. Is there anything Visual Studio specific which could be giving me the `compatibility error` messages?

Comment: And as if by magic, having just detached it in SQL Server Express Management Studio and re-added it in Visual Studio, it no longer reports compatibility issues. Hmmm. Something fishy is going on